# Capturing multichannel audio input in C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, speech-recognition, microphone

I'm developing a system that needs to capture audio from multiple microphones simultaneously and run a speech recognition model on the audio. I'm developing with Unity, but I wasn't able to find a plugin that supports this feature. So, maybe I could implement this in C# separate from the Unity MonoBehaviour environment.

I'm open to ideas. Maybe running this in Python and passing the data to Unity through a local server would work, but I'd need to implement a VOIP system.